# Contents of the CV for master's application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv, statement-of-purpose

I am applying as an international student for master's in computer science at the United States. I am preparing my CV for the application and I have mentioned my academic and work experience.

Should i mention my goal/objective in the CV mentioning why I wish to pursue the master's? Or is it sufficient if it is contained in the SOP?

Further is it fine if I just mention the title of a project/Internship? Since it is a major change, it seems to be irrelevant to an MS in CS for which i am applying to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, put that in your statement of purpose.  Your CV is a resume of what you've already done, not what you hope to do in the future. A CV is commonly much longer than a regular job resume because academics will list all their publications, patents, invited talks, awards, funding grants, etc. Really no limit as long as it happened.  The only things a CV should not contain are paths not taken (e.g., accepted into a program you decided not to attend) and stuff not yet done or happening now.

Your goals and and how you hope to get there belong in your SOP, the point of which is to be future-oriented, explaining what they should expect if they admit you.  (Avoid clichés of having been interested in computers since childhood.)

Comment: And also avoid the opposite error of using the SoP to make excuses for anything in the past. The past speaks for itself. As the writer here says: the SoP is future-oriented.

Comment: In physics, I have see lines on some CVs like "Won X fellowship [declined]". I personally prefer your advice of "a CV should not contain are paths not taken", but at least in some fields this does happen.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it happens, especially among those without many actual accomplishments to list.  Don't do it.  It's not a good look.